# Why ~(true^true) is not true? Boolean operators (negation) works for `unsigned char`s, but not for bools? (C++)

Tags: c++, boolean, boolean-expression, boolean-operations

I heard that often "everything" besides 0 is true. But now very strange things are happening to me... or I just think that I do it in correct way while I don't. Here's what is happening:

When I want to check if **a** is equivalent **b**, I can use `NOT(a XOR b)`. When I checked it for `unsigned char`'s, everything was ok, for example

```
unsigned char a = 5;
unsigned char b = 3;
unsigned char c = ~(a^b);
```

gave me `c == 249`:

**a** is: `00000101`, which is 5.

**b** is: `00000011`, which is 3.

**~(a^b)** is: `11111001`, which is 249.

Now, let's try this with `bool`'s.

```
cout << ~(true^true) << ~(true^false) << ~(false^true) << ~(false^false) << endl;
cout << ~(~(true^true)) << ~(~(true^false)) << ~(~(false^true)) << ~(~(false^false)) << endl;

if (~(true^true) == true)
    cout << "true";
else
    cout << "false";
```

This gives me in console:

```
-1-2-2-1
0110
false
```

while I expected the first line to be:

```
1001
```

After asking a friend, he advised me to try `!` instead of `~` and see if it will work correctly. And (I think) it works correctly now. But I don't understand why. Shouldn't boolean negation work for bools?

Comment: Boolean negation *does* work for booleans. It's *bitwise-NOT* that doesn't.

Comment: A `bool` has more than one bit. ~ flips each bit.

Comment: It *is* true, it's just not *equal* to `true`.

Comment: How many types of negations we have? I was using this page: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/boolean/ and there is only one mentioned.

Comment: Ok, I found this: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/operators/. 
But why bit-wise don't work and I have `-1`? Isn't `0` or `false` represented in this case as `00000000` ?

Comment: @Kusavil Kerrek got a nice answer, you should definately read it.

Comment: Thank you, I think I got it now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I heard that often "everything" besides 0 is true

It is valid for conditions as for example in the if statement (here and below I am citing the  C++Standard)

> The value of a condition that is an expression is the value of the
>   expression, contextually converted to bool for statements other than
>   switch

For example if you would write as

```
if (~(true^true) )
    cout << "true";
else
    cout << "false";
```

instead of your code snippet

```
if (~(true^true) == true)
    cout << "true";
else
    cout << "false";
```

or when the logical negation operator `!` is used

> 9 The operand of the logical negation operator ! is contextually
>   converted to bool (Clause 4); its value is true if the converted
>   operand is false and false otherwise. The type of the result is bool

As for operator `==` then

> 6 If both operands are of arithmetic or enumeration type, the usual
>   arithmetic conversions are performed on both operands; each of the
>   operators shall yield true if the specified relationship is true and
>   false if it is false.

That is in case of

```
if (~(true^true) == true)
```

the usual arithmetic conversion is applied that is boolean value true is converted to integer value 1 and it is not equal to the expression of the left operanf because internal binary representation of the left operand differs from 1 as showed the output of your first code snippet..

Comment: Great answer, now I understand much clearly what really is happening, thank you! Where I can find standard you are citing? I get a little confused while searching it in google.

Comment: @Kusavil You can find the Working Draft of the Standard at http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/

Answer (score 9):

You're misunderestimating the arithmetic conversions. When you say `~e` for some expression `e` of integral type, the value is first promoted to at-least-`int`, and same for `e1 ^ e2` (and for any arithmetic expressions, for that matter). So `true ^ true` first has its operands promoted to `int`, yielding `1 ^ 1`, which is indeed 0, and thus you end up with `~0`, which on your platform is `-1`.

You can vaguely make sense of your operation by converting the result back to `bool`:

```
std::cout << static_cast<bool>(~(true ^ true))
```

In your final problem, since you have an expression with the `==` operator where the two operands have different types, both operands are promoted to the common type, which is again `int`, and `-1` is different from `1`. Again, you can convert both operands to `bool` first to get the desired equality.

---

The meta lesson is that the built-in operators in C++ acting on integers really only operate on `int` and wider, but not on any of the shorter types (`bool`, `char`, `short`) (and similar considerations apply to passing integers through an ellipsis). While this may cause some confusion at times, it also simplifies the language rules a bit, I suppose. This is all part of the C heritage of C++.

Comment: "Misunderestimating" ? Is that a word, or did a joke just fly over my head ?

Comment: @Quentin: Can't it be both? :-)

Answer (score 3):

Considering your first example only,

```
~(true^true)
```

First, the operands of `^` are promoted to `int`, so that this is equivalent to

```
~(1^1)
```

Then xor of 1 with itself yields an all-zero bitpattern, which regardless of `int` representation denotes the value 0:

```
~0
```

This inverts every bit in the all-zeroes bitpattern for 0, resulting in a bitpattern with all bits 1, e.g. for 32-bit `int`,

```
int( 0xFFFFFFFF )
```

With the now almost universal two's complement form representation of signed integers this is then the value -1.

Your output is therefore

```
-1
```

Answer (score 2):

`~` is a bit-wise NOT.

e.g. ~0 is 255 for unsigned char, and 255 != `true`.

Answer (score 2):

There is a difference between logical negation and bitwise negation. bitwise negation flips the bits in variable, and logical negation flips the logical value, i.e. true/false. Consider for example the number 5, represented in binary as 101. If you flip just the bits (~5) you would get 11111010, which is not false, because only all zeros is false in c++. But if you compute (!5) you would get all zeros, which would work inside a condition.